# Number Format in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this number.

```
20.79
```

I need see the number as

```
20,79
```

Or

```
1.200,76 €
```

How can I change the . by , and add € currency?

Thanks!

Solution

```
app.filter('customCurrency', function(){
    return function(input, symbol, place){
        if(isNaN(input)){
            return input;
        } else {
            var symbol = symbol || '$';
            var place = place === undefined ? true : place;
            if(place === true){
                return symbol + input;
            } else{
                var new_input = input.replace(".", ",");
                return new_input + symbol;
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Google: "AngularJS filter"

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this before, but I don't see how can I change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by simply changing your Locale to match the European currency:

Import this library

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.6.0/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
```

In your html

```
<div>{{ myNumber | currency: '€' }}</div>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.myNumber = 1220.79;
```

Result: `1.220,79 €`

Please check it: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hd84335/nfzhrnpc/3/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) filter:

In your Angular controller:

```
$scope.myNumber = 20.79;
```

In your HTML page:

```
<div>{{myNumber | currency}}</div>
```

---

**Update:** If you need to display in €, 2 options:

- Set your locale to your country: `<script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>` (best option).
- Display it without currency filter: `{{(myNumber | number: 2) + " €"}}`.

[**Demo on JSFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/z5shgzxw/)